# OpenSSH-Portable trying to install X11?

Tags: ssh, freebsd

I'm trying to upgrade OpenSSL, OpenSSH, and Apache22 on a FreeBSD 8.1 system.  I'm already running OpenSSH-Portable, so that's not really a problem.

Where I run into trouble is that `openssh-portable` is trying to install `libXext`.  How can I tell this port to ignore X11 requirements?

Comment: Why would you want to?  What is the harm?  It is just a library to permit X11 forwarding.

Comment: It is actually failing a requirement and not able to install.  So it is blocking the package being installed.

Comment: The only build/run dep I see for security/openssh-portable is perl5. What options have you set in the config dialog? Which dependency is failing?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenters that there's something unusual going on here.  I do know that OpenSSH supports X11 forwarding, which might require `libXext` in some circumstances, but that seems unlikely to me, as the `sshd` that comes with FreeBSD has no explicit X dependencies:

```
royce@atoz$ ldd `which sshd`
/usr/sbin/sshd:
        libssh.so.5 => /usr/lib/libssh.so.5 (0x800681000)
        libutil.so.8 => /lib/libutil.so.8 (0x8007cc000)
        libz.so.5 => /lib/libz.so.5 (0x8008dc000)
        libwrap.so.6 => /usr/lib/libwrap.so.6 (0x8009f1000)
        libpam.so.5 => /usr/lib/libpam.so.5 (0x800afa000)
        libbsm.so.3 => /usr/lib/libbsm.so.3 (0x800c02000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.10 => /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.10 (0x800d1d000)
        libgssapi.so.10 => /usr/lib/libgssapi.so.10 (0x800e37000)
        libkrb5.so.10 => /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.10 (0x800f41000)
        libasn1.so.10 => /usr/lib/libasn1.so.10 (0x8010b0000)
        libcrypto.so.6 => /lib/libcrypto.so.6 (0x801232000)
        libcrypt.so.5 => /lib/libcrypt.so.5 (0x8014d2000)
        libc.so.7 => /lib/libc.so.7 (0x8015f2000)
        libhx509.so.10 => /usr/lib/libhx509.so.10 (0x801834000)
        libcom_err.so.5 => /usr/lib/libcom_err.so.5 (0x801974000)
        libmd.so.5 => /lib/libmd.so.5 (0x801a76000)
        libroken.so.10 => /usr/lib/libroken.so.10 (0x801b86000)
```

Have you changed any of the port's options?  If so, a good next troubleshooting step would be for you to post the contents of `/var/db/ports/openssh/options`.  The current default options in openssh-portable's `Makefile` are as follows, and do not trigger the installation of libXext for me:

```
OPTIONS=   PAM             "Enable pam(3) support"                         on \
           TCP_WRAPPERS    "Enable tcp_wrappers support"                   on \
           LIBEDIT         "Enable readline support to sftp(1)"            on \
           SUID_SSH        "Enable suid SSH (Recommended off)"             off \
           BSM             "Enable OpenBSM Auditing"                       off \
           KERBEROS        "Enable kerberos (autodetection)"               off \
           KERB_GSSAPI     "Enable Kerberos/GSSAPI patch (req: GSSAPI)"    off \
           OPENSSH_CHROOT  "Enable CHROOT support"                         off \
           HPN             "Enable HPN-SSH patch"                          off \
           LPK             "Enable LDAP Public Key (LPK) patch"            off \
           X509            "Enable x509 certificate patch"                 off \
           FILECONTROL     "Enable file control patch (broken)"            off \
           OVERWRITE_BASE  "OpenSSH overwrite base"                        off
```

I'm not enough of a user of most of these options to immediately see if any of them require any X11.  But if you trace each of the dependencies, one of them may need `libXext`, and any ones that you've toggled are more likely to be the culprit.

Generally speaking, if you don't want anything X-related for **any** of your ports (which is often the case on a server), you can add `WITHOUT_X11` to `/etc/make.conf`, but that's a shot in the dark that you could try as a diagnostic step, and doesn't actually reveal the root cause of your issue.  If you're just interested in a quick fix, that might help.